# Java/ASM: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 even though list is 1024 elements long

Tags: java, arrays, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to understand ASM and am currently stuck at chapter 2.2.4 in the handbook. This should be a simple Java question though.

The example code I'm trying to understand has this line in it called `byte[] b1 = ...;`.
Since this is not a complete statement (I even tried it out!) I replaced it with `byte[] b1 = new byte[1024];`.

When I compile however I get this weird error message:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`

called three lines later (`classReader.accept(classWriter, 0);`). Here's the full code and the full error message:

```
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;

public class ModifyClassExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] b1 = new byte[1024];
        ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(0);
        ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(b1);
        classReader.accept(classWriter, 0);
        byte[] b2 = classWriter.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readStringish(ClassReader.java:3726)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:3741)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:454)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)
    at ModifyClassExample.main(ModifyClassExample.java:9)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried reducing the size of the byte array. That's why I know this error pops up at array lenghts of 14+.

Needless to say I need more than that.

Comment: @67af7af3-67f3-48bf-98c5-d9155c thanks... this was indeed the error. I updated the title and body. You can submit this as an answer if you wish to do so.

Comment: Don't put Solved in the question title; click the "accept" checkbox under an answer to mark the question solved.  (If the existing answer doesn't cover everything, you can write your own answer.)

Comment: "When I compile however I get this weird error message" - no, an exception is what happens when you *run* code. It's really important to understand the difference between compile-time errors and execution-time exceptions.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks. I know that very well. The (Solved) title was meant to be temporary only however since 67af7af3-67f3-48bf-98c5-d9155c solved the problem in a comment. I asked him to transform the answer into an actual answer so I could mark it. This was to ensure he would get the credit he deserves.

Comment: Ok, well in future don't edit like that even temporarily, please.  It's fine for a question to still be "open" for some time after discussion in comments points out the problem.  You can post an answer yourself, or like you did encourage the commenter to post it in case there's more to say in a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not providing any class data in the byte array `b1` so it will not work. You can however construct a ClassReader from a standard java class such as

```
ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader("java.lang.Runnable");.
```

I'd recommend creating a test class with various constructs and use that as your test subject.

Or use the example in 2.2.3 to generate the data - the last line produces the byte array.